# Ambitions - Are they Real or just an Illusion

Tags: karma, meditation, modern-world

Do our passions and ambitions need to be fulfilled or is it just an illusion created by our mind? According to the dhamma, is it considered to be helpful or unhelpful to fulfill goals?

Comment: Why do you want to chase suffering ? It is like asking the bull to hit you. Dreams are of consequence. It is always a good practice to believe in good dreams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it is good to have goals, but the **"why"** and **intensity** is very important. If you thirst for it, because, let's say, you expect outer praise from someone, that is not very wise and will eventually lead to disappointment and frustration. **Your intention is very important (why you want something)**. If you think, speak and act in such a way that supports a relative harmonious life for both you and others -then go for it! Another thing to consider: **Usually people have a rather short sighted view and wear pink coloured glasses. They focus only on the short term pleasures, see only the beauty in the object (or pleasure), but don't consider the long(er) term drawbacks**. For example: Humans enjoy sensual pleasures because they feel good (now) and therefore they repeat it over and over again.  This might not sound problematic, but this causes all kinds of addictions like binge eating, alcoholism, drug addiction, sex addiction followed by lack of self control, rationalizations ("it's fine what I'm doing".. so basically short sighted), a mind which is never restless, attachment, problems with oneself (self hatred, lethargic), problems with friends/family and even with society.  If you don't have what you crave/if it's gone/if someone takes it away from you you become angry, upset, lament etc. People never ask themselves, why they had to repeat the sensual pleasures over and over again**.

**And what, Bhikkhu, was the cause for you indulging in the sense pleasure over and over again? Impermanence, that is, the shortness/transience of the pleasure, is the first reason. Craving for the pleasure is the second reason. Attachment (which follows from craving) is the third**.

This wasn't said by the Buddha. I just like his way of words